# Anomalies, 2-cocycles and (D+1)-cocycles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, representation-theory, quantum-anomalies, cohomology

I'm learning about anomalies and I'm a bit confused about their relationships to 2-cocycles and 3-cocycles (in the group cohomology $H^{\bullet}(G, U(1))$). The below might only apply to 't Hooft anomalies.

I read in some places (e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/687521/210239)) that an anomaly corresponds to a nontrivial 2-cocycle, i.e. when the Hilbert space transforms under a projective representation.

Elsewhere (e.g. p4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09542)) 't Hooft anomalies in a $D$-dimensional theory correspond instead to non-trivial *(D+1)-cocycles*; later in s2.2 the author refers to a `nontrivial extension with a trivial anomaly'. I asked a prof and he said the anomaly is the obstruction to uplifting the projective representation to a genuine representation. But I was under the impression that you could always uplift to a genuine representation of a central extension.

Would appreciate any clarification/classification/pointers to references where the two things are discussed together - and of course corrections for anything I have misunderstood.

Comment: [Due diligence](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0634).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm not sure what you mean. Could you indicate which section might be helpful? The word cocycle does not appear, and the cohomology bits I can find seem to be about specific scenarios and are quite involved. Do you know something that addresses my question a bit more directly?

Comment: [Quicker](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(85)91472-8). Your must slug through the entire Bilal review. Cocycles are  implicit there.

Comment: sorry. what is your question, exactly?

Comment: I would like to know which cocycles are considered a diagnostic of an anomaly, and which anomalies are associated with which cocycle degree. And how the different degrees interact - e.g. if the 2-cocycle is only relevant when the higher cocycle is trivial.